# How do I use openmesh and igl libraries in Python if both are not available for python2.7 or python3.9?

Tags: python, pip, conda, libraries, openmesh

I have been trying to use some code which is uses openmesh and igl libraries.

Unfortunately, the only way to install igl I found was via conda into its Python 3.9 environment ([conda install -c conda-forge igl](https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/)). Openmesh on the other hand I could only install via outdated pip 20.x into Python 2.7 ([pip install openmesh](https://pypi.org/project/openmesh/)).

How could I use code, which necessitates both libraries? Is there an easy way to import the methods from one of the two libraries into either Python 2.7 or 3.9 environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `openmesh` on Conda Forge refers to the OpenMesh software, which is not equivalent to the Python bindings (`openmesh` on PyPI). The latter goes by `openmesh-python` on Conda Forge and has builds for Python 2.7, 3.6, and 3.7.

Second, I wouldn't recommend trying to install into an existing environment. Rather, specify exactly the packages that you require and let Conda resolve the dependency versions.

Using the command:

```bash
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge igl openmesh-python
```

solves without issue for me, and results in a Python 3.7 environment that can have both `igl` and `openmesh` installed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!! Only thing I now have to figure out is why it works in terminal and not in tmux..

Comment: @tlk13 yeah `tmux` + `conda` is a whole other thing. I abandoned `tmux` years ago for `screen` simply because it mucks around with the `PATH` in ways that interfere with Conda functionality. Workarounds can be found through searching, either here or SuperUser or Unix SE sites.

Comment: nice, thanks. never been a huge fan of tmux either way, my former tutor recommended it to me and I just went with it. but will try out screen then!

Answer (score 0):

Libigl is now [also available on pip](https://pypi.org/project/libigl/). It has wheels for a variety of python3 and it seems now the openmesh wheels on pypi also support python3

Comment: Hi, is python support still in beta? For a mesh of 50k verts, igl.principal_curvature kills my kernel every time .

Comment: something might be wrong with your mesh, I just tried >400K and it works fine. Feel free to post  an issue on github with your data

Comment: Yes, there were some floating faces with zero areas. It works fine after I removed them. Maybe you can make it more robust? :)